# I'm unable to save file in the directory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to store an image to a newly created directory, at first try it's working fine, but in the next and further try it's showing the following error:

```
C:\testing\file.js:48
                if(err) throw err
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open 'C:\testing\hello\images\pic.jpg'
at Error (native)
```

My code is:

```
const dir ='./'+hello+'/images'

            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
               mkdirp(dir, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err
            })
            }
            fs.writeFile(dir+'/pic.jpg',base64 string, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
                if(err) throw err
                console.log('File created')
                                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have finished writing the file to the other location? This error is thrown because the file appears to be open by the OS. Try writing the file again inside the callback.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are talking about it would be helpful for me if you can give an example code

Answer (score 0):

I believe pic.jpg is already available in that directory. 
i.e why it is throwing error.
Try with different name.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of try finally I understood the problem and i.e here in above code the file creation process is async so before creation of file the data is trying to be inserted which throws the error but by using sync process(mkdirp.sync(path)) my problem was solved .